# Inconsistent Font Sizes in Colorbar Legend Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, legend-properties

I am working on data visualization using matplotlib in Python. One of the visual elements in my plot is a colorbar legend that represents different values with corresponding colors. However, I have noticed that the font sizes of the colorbar legend labels are inconsistent, which hinders readability and affects the overall aesthetic of the plot.

To address this issue, I attempted to set the font size explicitly using the set_label and set_tick_params methods of the colorbar object. However, despite specifying the desired font size, the font sizes of the legend labels remained inconsistent.

Are there any suggestions?

Here is the code I use - the input is a dictonary with node ids from a graph an corresponding values

```
import pathlib
from typing import Union, Dict, Optional

import osmnx as ox

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors, cm
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

from configs.default import get_default_config
from preprocessing.graph_loader import GraphLoader

root_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute()


class GraphMapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = get_default_config()['ds']
        self.graph = GraphLoader().graph

    def plot_dict_on_graph_as_heatmap(
            self,
            dictionary: Dict,
            title: str,
            filename: Optional[str] = None,
            font: str = 'Consolas',  # 'Times New Roman',
            fontsize: int = 25
    ) -> None:
        cmap = plt.cm.inferno
        maximum_value = max([dictionary[k] for k in dictionary.keys()])
        minimum_value = max(min(dictionary.values()), 1)
        norm = colors.LogNorm(vmin=minimum_value, vmax=maximum_value)
        sm = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

        node_color = [
            sm.to_rgba(dictionary[n])
            if dictionary[n] > 0
            else sm.to_rgba(minimum_value)
            for n in self.graph.nodes(data=False)
        ]

        node_size = [10 if dictionary[n] > 0 else 0 for n in self.graph.nodes(data=False)]

        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(
            self.graph,
            node_size=node_size,
            edge_linewidth=.5,
            node_color=node_color,
            edge_color='#333333',
            bgcolor='w',
            show=False,
            close=False,
        )

        cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ax=ax, shrink=0.8, pad=0.01)
        font_properties = FontProperties(
            family=font,
            size=fontsize,
        )

        if title != '':
            cbar.set_label(title, fontproperties=font_properties)

        # formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: r"${:.0f} \times 10^3$".format(x / 1e3))
        # cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        # cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=fontsize)
        # cbar.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=fontsize)
        cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), fontproperties=font_properties)

        plt.subplots_adjust(
            left=0.01,
            bottom=0.01,
            right=0.99,
            top=0.99,
            wspace=0.01,
            hspace=0.01
        )

        if filename is not None:
            plt.savefig(root_dir / "visualizations" / (str(filename) + ".pdf"), bbox_inches='tight')

        plt.show()
```

Here is the output image:

[The value 10^3 has the format I am looking for, while the other values are not correctly formatted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upHNI.png)

I tried

- setting font properties, using `FontProperties`
- setting font properties for each tick label in colorbar using

```
for label in cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(fontprops)
```

or

```
cbar.set_ticklabels([label.get_text() for label in cbar.ax.get_yticklabels()], fontproperties=fontprops)
```

- i tried a formatter

```
formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:.0f}')
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), fontproperties=fontprops)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not really find out what the issue was (especially since other dictonaries worked fine), but setting a default font/fontsize worked fine:

```
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Consolas'
mpl.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'light' 
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 25
```